# Difference between Edge and HA clusters artifactory

Tags: artifactory, high-availability

Reading documentation about HA and Edge clusters Artifactory, can not find detail compression between them, there is documentation about their installation. What's main points of difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

This document has a comparison table: https://jfrog.com/help/r/get-started-with-the-jfrog-platform/jfrog-artifactory-edge

The main point is to view the edge node as a lightweight version of Artifactory. It does not have any sort of direct uploads to it. Rather it is used for making artifacts available to users at edge locations.

The artifacts get to the edge node via release bundles or replication from a main artifactory to the edge node using smart remote repositories that mirror local repositories on your main Artifactory.

Comment: What is the benefit to use this lightweight version?

Comment: Licenses are much cheaper for the edge nodes :)

Comment: Thanks. What's the drawbacks in terms of performance?

Comment: No drawback in performance. Only in functionality.